# How to register logback JMXConfigurator to WebSphere custom MBeanServer?

Tags: websphere, logback, jmx

I tried to put `<jmxConfigurator/>` in logback configuration file. I am able to connect jconsole to local JVM running unit tests and interact with the logback mbean. However, when I deploy my web application to a remote Websphere application server and connect jconsole to that remote JVM, I can't see the logback mbean in the MBeans panel.

As a comparison, the web application is built with spring boot, which also register some MBeans by default. I can see MBeans of spring boot in both scenarios.

I investigated a bit further and found out logback always get MBeanServer instance from `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()`, while spring uses different approaches in Websphere/Weblogic environment.

**It appears that in Websphere environment, the MBeanServer instance exposed for remote connection is NOT the default PlatformMBeanServer.**

So the question is, how can I register the logback mbean to the WebSphere custom MBeanServer, rather than the default PlatformMBeanServer?

WebSphere custom MBeanServer is favoured because it is better integrated with security and clustering capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround by extending `JMXConfigurator`.

Just for the record, there is no document endorsing such extension, and I didn't test it with **multiple web-applications**.

This class inherited most behaviors from `JMXConfigurator`, but it will register to / unregister from the `MBeanServer` that is injected by Spring.

```
@ManagedResource(objectName = AnnotatedJMXConfigurator.NAME, description = "Logback Configuration Management Bean")
@Component
public class AnnotatedJMXConfigurator extends JMXConfigurator {

    public static final String NAME = "xxx.ch.qos.logback.classic:Name=default,Type=ch.qos.logback.classic.jmx.JMXConfigurator";

    private static final LoggerContext CONTEXT = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    private static final ObjectName OBJECT_NAME;

    static {
        try {
            OBJECT_NAME = new ObjectName(NAME);
        } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    public AnnotatedJMXConfigurator(MBeanServer mbs) {
        super(CONTEXT, mbs, OBJECT_NAME);
    }
}
```